# How to run a .bat file continuously using task scheduler?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple batch script which is coping file from a folder and then move those files to a different folder. i set a up a task scheduler which working fine. but if another task run the cmd before previous task end, it will mixed up with the copy/move file job. is there anyway we can set the task scheduler that next task will run "only if previous task end"?

here is the screenshot i currently set
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu056.png

Comment: If a certain resource exists (e.g. a file), have the batch file exit. Otherwise, create the resource, do the work, then delete the resource. You might want to consider what happens if the batch file fails to complete for some reason.

Comment: @ikegami, that is one way, the problem with `cmd` is that if the script unexpectedly exit, the lock file will remain and the script will not run again. Though, as Compo mentioned, this is probably "one of those" scenario's and there are better methods, the one way that does work is `tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq my_job_run" | findstr /i "cmd.exe"` then `if not errorlevel 1 exit` then `title my_job_run` This way, if the script ends, there is no `cmd` process with the title and the next job can execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Ikegami, You could use a lock file to test if the batch file is running and let the same process delete the lock file when the script is done. You have to be sure though that the script cannot exit unexpectedly.

Another way is to add the following to the top of your `batch-file`

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq my_job_run" | findstr /i "cmd.exe"
if not errorlevel 1 exit
title my_job_run
```

This will check if a process by the name of `cmd.exe` exists with the window title of `my_job_run` if it does, `exit` and if it does not exist, continue and create the title, where the next run will detect it and not run the script again.